# Mysql, Concat on specified length

Tags: mysql

I was trying to find a way in mysql functions do the the following:

```
'ssssssttttttttrrrriiiinnnngggg' // I have this string
```

I want to take only 10 letters then concate '...'(3 dots), But i only want to concat to strings with over 10 letters so for example:

```
'123456string' // Will result: '123456stri...'
'strin6' // Will result: 'strin6'
'str123456ing' // Will result: 'str123456i...'
'asd23456' // Will result: 'asd23456'
```

I was trying substr, lpad and concat combinations, If anyone got the correct functions combination i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: In my eyes, it is more comfortable to do your goal outside of a database management system. Your are more flexible if some requirements about the cutting rule does change.

Comment: Thank you guys i am testing....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  select case when length(mystring) <= 10 then 
      mystring 
  else 
      concat(left(mystring, 7), '...') 
  end as mycol
  ...
```

Comment: I think the OP rather expected `... LEFT(mystring, 10)...` (but +1 anyways).

Answer (score 3):

Use an additional IF to check the length of the value first:

SELECT IF(LENGTH(str) > 10, CONCAT(SUBSTR(str, 1, 10), "..."), str) AS ...

Answer (score 3):

select if(length(string1)>10,concat(substr(string1,1,10),"..."),string1) as mystring